# subset first and last consecutive value from pandas df col - python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to subset a df by returning the first and last consecutive value from a pandas col. `Drop_duplciates` won't work because it doesn't account for consecutive groupings. I'm using `.shift()` (below) but this only returns the last consecutive value, where I want the first and last.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"Item":['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'A', 'A'], 
           "Val1":[-20, -21, -20, -20, -20, -21, -20, -23, -22], 
           "Val2":[150, 151, 150, 148, 149, 150, 151, 150, 148]
           })

df1 = df[df['Item'].ne(df['Item'].shift())]

print(df1)
```

intended output:

```
  Item  Val1  Val2
0    A   -20   150
2    A   -20   150
3    B   -20   148
6    B   -20   151
7    A   -23   150
8    A   -22   148
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to compare against both the forward and backward shifted values so that you can find the start and finish of each group:

```py
df1 = df[(df['Item'].ne(df['Item'].shift())) | 
         (df['Item'].ne(df['Item'].shift(-1)))]
```

Output:

```
  Item  Val1  Val2
0    A   -20   150
2    A   -20   150
3    B   -20   148
6    B   -20   151
7    A   -23   150
8    A   -22   148
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `groupby` and `nth`

```
df.groupby(df['Item'].ne(df['Item'].shift()).cumsum(),as_index=False).nth([0,-1])
```

Output:

```
  Item  Val1  Val2
0    A   -20   150
2    A   -20   150
3    B   -20   148
6    B   -20   151
7    A   -23   150
8    A   -22   148
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df['group'] = (df['Item'] != df['Item'].shift()).cumsum()
cols = ['group', 'Item']
df[~df.duplicated(cols, keep='last') | ~df.duplicated(cols, keep='first')]
```

Output:

```
  Item  Val1  Val2  group
0    A   -20   150      1
2    A   -20   150      1
3    B   -20   148      2
6    B   -20   151      2
7    A   -23   150      3
8    A   -22   148      3
```